# Is it possible to lose weight doing brain exercise?

Tags: brain, energy-metabolism, exercise

According to this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basal_metabolic_rate#Biochemistry) human brain consume a comparable amount of energy with skeletal muscle. So is it possible to do some brain exercise (calculate something in mind etc.) instead of physical exercise to lose weight?
More specific questions:

1. Is it theoretically possible?
2. Is there any real-life example?
3. What kind of brain activity require more energy?
4. Pros and cons (brain exercise vs. physical exercise)

Comment: There have been several studies that show that even physical exercise itself isn't that good at causing weight loss unless you work out at athlete levels; dietary intake is much more important. Health.SE would be a more appropriate place to address that, however. As far as the brain, most of the energy the brain uses goes to just maintaining brain activity, metabolism doesn't change much during waking hours. Having seizures might cause a bit more energy use but I wouldn't suggest that for health.

Comment: only way to use serious calories is by upping heart rate to 100 - 140.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No** The amount of calories the brain consumes is basically the same whether it is doing anything or no. Best case only about 3% increase in calories consumed by the brain or about 50 calories per day, which is miniscule and most studies do not even show that much.

Additionally buring calories is only important for weight loss once consumption is controlled. It is too easy to out eat any amount of exercise.

https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/thinking-hard-calories/